# Use local database from master in MS SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have created a local db using SQLEXPRESS through Visual Basic.

I intend to use LINQ to connect to the database from the application. Here is my statement to initially connect to the database:

```
Dim db As New DataContext("Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security=True;")
```

Ideally, my database would be entered for Initial Catalog, but that was giving me authentication errors for some reason. Now that this statement executes, my next step is to connect to my specific database. However, when I try to connect with a statement like this:

```
Dim TestCommand = db.ExecuteCommand("Use MyDB.mdf")
```

I get an error that the database does not exist.

When I query my database with the following commands:

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
```

The returned values are master, tempdb, model, msdb, and C:USERS\MY NAME\DOCUMENTS\MyDB.mdf

I have tried the above "TestCommand" writing out the directory for the database, but I get an error at "C:".

So, my db exists, but can someone explain to me the syntax I should use to "USE" my database?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `use` command this way! You must connect to the application's database directly by setting it as Initial Catalog. If you're not authorized to do so, a `use` command won't let you either, by the way. So you have to fix the authorization for the database: create a login for your windows account in Sql Server Management Studio and grant it read/write access to the application's database.